# Checking if all columns of a database are less than the values in another database

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have the following two databases:

```
Limits
ValueName || Limit
Test1        21
Test2        22
Test3        20
...
```

and

```
Results
Name || Test1 || Test2 || Test3 || ...
Trial   20       23      19
Trial1  19       19      19
...
```

Is there a way to make a select statement get all the results with a value under the limit, without having to put a separate statement for each row in the limits table?

Comment: Fix your schema. Results requires a significant redesign

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Results schema, instead of having this horizontal long columns (test1, test2, ... testN) add Limit's `valuleName` as FK so you have something like : 
Results

```
Name | _valueName | Value
Trial | Test1 | 20
Trial | Test2 | 23
...
Trial1 | Test1 | 19
```

Query:

```
SELECT r.Name, r.Value FROM Results r INNER JOIN Limits l
ON r._valueName = l.valueName
WHERE r.Value <= l.Limit
```